# Exception: Access denined: DriveApp when trying to setTrashed(true)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, access-denied

The context:

- I writing a script to copy a doc template and grab the data from the sheet to filling into placeholder in the template and update the link back to the sheet.
- It also have a mode to delete old file if there's a link existing from last run.
- I have no problem running it with the account that I use to create the script, but when using different account to run it, its cause `Exception: Access denined: DriveApp` (access to the folder was grant to the 2nd account)

Although I already try to set the access writer to anyone before the `setTrashed(true)` by using:

```js
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'anyone',
    value: '',
  },
  oldDocId
);
Utilities.sleep(2000); // sleep for 2 sec to make sure the call is finished
```

or even try to set the writer to the current user by:

```js
const currentUserEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    value: currentUserEmail,
  },
  oldDocId
);
Utilities.sleep(2000); // sleep for 2 sec to make sure the call is finished
```

The folder that I'm save the document is belong to an organization, I noticed that the document automatically set owner to the admin, not the one who run the script, but its running ok on 2nd run if using the same user (not the admin).

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem you are having is that the permissions for access to the folder are not been added properly; remember that even if you add the permissions on the code using:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'anyone',
    value: '',
  },
  oldDocId
);
```

The one that is running the script doesn't have permissions over the folder, so they cannot add the permission to the folder, which generated the error message.

There are 2 workarounds that you can do to solve the issue, the one I recommend is to share the folder with the users that will use the script using the web UI of Google Drive.

The other one, is to use a 3rd party to use impersonation in Google Apps Script with the [OAuth library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2), this only work if you have Google Workspace. If you have Workspace, you can create a user for, and share the folder with that user, and impersonate that user inside your apps script.

Comment: thanks for the support, but I already mention that the 2nd account already have the right to access the folder stored all the document and I can perform delete on the Drive web UI, I'll try the 3rd party option and update later.